# WideVine support on JxBrowser

Tags: javafx, jxbrowser, widevine

Just trying to find out what has to be done to be able to enable the Widevine Media plugin that is supported in Google Chrome to the JxBrowser as this seems to becoming quite a popular plugin for the pages that we need to access.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JxBrowser is based on Chromium engine that doesn't support Widevine Media plugin at all. Google Chrome supports it, Chromium - doesn't. We tried several approaches to enable Widevine Media plugin in Chromium, but we didn't manage to successfully enable and use it. At least, Netflix still didn't work.

We will go back to this question later. Probably in January 2016. For now, it's not clear whether it's possible to enable Widevine in Chromium engine or not.

Comment: Thank you Vladimir for your response, Widevine support is the only thing holding me back at the moment from using JxBrowser in our project as it is a big part of what we need it for.